# How to: jQuery cycle lite plugin (image rotator plugin) manually set images by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, image-rotation

Hello I am using [jQuery cycle lite plugin (image rotator plugin)](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/lite/), and I want to use the middle example (click triggers) but instead of setting the IDs of the prev and next button, I'd like to manually set the image ID.

My aim is to have a list of thumbs on the bottom of the page, and when thumb clicked set the large image in the 'slideshow' div.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade to the [full Cycle Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/), you [get this functionality for free](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pager2.html)

Comment: I have already a few pages who use the lite plugin, what are the consequences?
does the full version include the lite functions as well?

Comment: well, I found out that the plain cycle function works as in lite except one issue: it causes the images to become small.

Comment: I didn't manage to use, I am not looking for something else; I am just looking for how to use it.
I don't see the thumbnails.

Comment: If you could detail where you stand, and what type of problems you're having... ?

Comment: I played around and found the solution, you have to explicitly set both the large and the thumbnail's size.